# Odoo dividing two float fields - AttributeError

Tags: python, odoo

Can anyone help please with the below:
I'm trying to divide two float fields but I'm getting an error

```
AttributeError: 'stock.picking' object has no attribute 'calculate_reserved_per'
```

here's my code:

```
from odoo import models, fields, api

class PickingTotalQty(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'stock.picking'

    sum_dmd_qty = fields.Float(compute='calculate_dmd_qty', string='Total Demand Quantity')
    sum_reserved_qty = fields.Float(compute='calculate_reserved_qty', string='Total Reserved Quantity')
    reserved_qty_per = fields.Float(compute='calculate_reserved_per', string='Reserved Quantity (%)')

    def calculate_dmd_qty(self):
        for rs in self:
            dmdqty = 0
            for line in rs.move_lines:
                dmdqty += line.product_uom_qty
        rs.sum_dmd_qty = dmdqty

    def calculate_reserved_qty(self):
        for rs in self:
            reservedqty = 0
            for line in rs.move_lines:
                reservedqty += line.reserved_availability
        rs.sum_reserved_qty = reservedqty

    @api.depends('sum_reserved_qty', 'sum_dmd_qty')
    def calculate_reserved_per(self):
        for rec in self:
            rec.reserved_qty_per = rec.sum_reserved_qty / rec.sum_dmd_qty
```

Comment: If you have already restarted the server check the indentation of the `calculate_reserved_per` method (I fixed it).

Comment: @Kenly thank you very much, you saved my day, could you please help how can I add "%" symbol next to field result?

Comment: Do you need something like the account view [amount](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/account/views/account_view.xml#L907) field

Comment: thank you, yes I did that but now I'm getting a new error "ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero"

Comment: Make sure `rec.sum_dmd_qty` is different from `Zero` before deviding.

Comment: yea I did that thank you, but I'm facing now a strange case, now everything is working and it showing in the form view as well but when I added the same field in tree view it showing the result is "0.00" for all lines.

Comment: I preferred adding an answer instead of answering in comments, check my answer below, and if you need anything else please comment my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already restarted the server check the indentation of the `calculate_reserved_per` method and make sure `rec.sum_dmd_qty` is different from `Zero` before dividing.

The strange behavior you are facing is the result of the indentation of the last line in both methods: `calculate_dmd_qty` and `calculate_reserved_qty` which ignore all records except the last one. In the form view, the method is called with a recordset containing one record, the current record.

To correct that, move the last line of each method inside the for-loop.

`sum_dmd_qty` and `sum_reserved_qty` are computed fields that depends on `move_lines.product_uom_qty` and `move_lines.reserved_availability` respectively and it should be used to specify when to recompute theire values using `@api.depends`.

You can use the accounting invoice [_compute_amount](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/12.0/addons/account/models/account_invoice.py#L55) as a reference and merge the three methods in one method that compute the value of the three fields.

***Example:***

```
@api.depends("move_lines.product_uom_qty", "move_lines.reserved_availability")
def _calculate_quantities(self):
    for picking in self:
        dmd_qty = 0
        reserved_qty = 0
        for move in picking.move_lines:
            dmd_qty += move.product_uom_qty
            reserved_qty += move.reserved_availability

        picking.sum_dmd_qty = dmd_qty
        picking.sum_reserved_qty = reserved_qty

        if picking.sum_dmd_qty:
            picking.reserved_qty_per = picking.sum_reserved_qty / picking.sum_dmd_qty
```

> I did not use `@api.one` because it is not available in Odoo13

Comment: Hi @Kenly, thank you very much for your help, as I mentioned before that's my last code is working as well inside the form view, but when I added the same field to the picking tree view as column it showing 0.00 value for all record

Comment: I was separated the question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62852510/odoo-float-field-not-display-value-on-tree-view