# Odoo - float field not display value on tree view

Tags: python, odoo

I have added custom float field to form and I used that field to display on tree view

but actually inside the form the field is calculated the correct value and working correctly but in the tree view column it's showing 0.00 value for all records.. why?

here's my model code:

```
from odoo import models, fields, api

class PickingTotalQty(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'stock.picking'

    sum_dmd_qty = fields.Float(compute='calculate_dmd_qty', string='Total Demand Quantity')
    sum_reserved_qty = fields.Float(compute='calculate_reserved_qty', string='Total Reserved Quantity')
    reserved_qty_per = fields.Float(compute='calculate_reserved_per', string='Reserved (%)')

    def calculate_dmd_qty(self):
        for rs in self:
            dmdqty = 0
            for line in rs.move_lines:
                dmdqty += line.product_uom_qty
        rs.sum_dmd_qty = dmdqty

    def calculate_reserved_qty(self):
        for rs in self:
            reservedqty = 0
            for line in rs.move_lines:
                reservedqty += line.reserved_availability
        rs.sum_reserved_qty = reservedqty

    @api.depends('sum_reserved_qty', 'sum_dmd_qty')
    def calculate_reserved_per(self):
        for rec in self:
            if rec.sum_dmd_qty > 0:
                rec.reserved_qty_per = rec.sum_reserved_qty / rec.sum_dmd_qty
```

and here is XML view code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <data>
        <record id="inherit_stock_picking_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">Stock Picking</field>
            <field name="model">stock.picking</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_picking_form"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="/form/sheet/notebook" position="after">
                    <group>
                        <group>
                            <field name="reserved_qty_per" nolabel="0"/>
                        </group>
                    </group>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
        <record id="inherit_stock_picking_tree_view2" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">Stock Picking2</field>
            <field name="model">stock.picking</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.vpicktree"/>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <xpath expr="//field[@name='state']" position="after">
                      <field name="reserved_qty_per"/>
                </xpath>
            </field>
        </record>
    </data>
</odoo>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `sum` value is reinitialized for each record and assigned outside the for loops, the calculation will not work except for the last record in the tree view. the methods are called with a recordset, in the form view it is called with a recordset containing only the one record, and this is why it works in the form view and not in the tree view.

To correct that issue move the last line of the two first methods inside the first loop.

The depends decorator is missing, try to add it.

***Example:***

```
@api.depends("move_lines.product_uom_qty")
def calculate_dmd_qty(self):
    for rs in self:
        dmdqty = 0
        for line in rs.move_ids_without_package:
            dmdqty += line.product_uom_qty
        rs.sum_dmd_qty = dmdqty

@api.depends("move_lines.reserved_availability")
def calculate_reserved_qty(self):
    for rs in self:
        reservedqty = 0
        for line in rs.move_ids_without_package:
            reservedqty += line.reserved_availability
        rs.sum_reserved_qty = reservedqty
```

***Edit:***

```
<odoo>
    <record id="view_picking_form" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">view.picking.form</field>
        <field name="model">stock.picking</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.view_picking_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr='//notebook' position="after">
                <group>
                    <field name="reserved_qty_per"/>
                </group>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>

    <record id="vpicktree" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">view.vpicktree</field>
        <field name="model">stock.picking</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="stock.vpicktree"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="state" position="before">
                <field name="reserved_qty_per"/>
            </field>
        </field>
    </record>
</odoo>
```

Comment: i got an error that "Field `sum_dmd_qty` does not exist"

Comment: I'm using Odoo 12 CE

Comment: it not showing in whicj line but I reduced the code as below and it showing the same error

Comment: sum_dmd_qty = fields.Float(compute='calculate_dmd_qty', string='Total Demand Quantity')
#    sum_reserved_qty = fields.Float(compute='calculate_reserved_qty', string='Total Reserved Quantity')
#    reserved_qty_per = fields.Float(compute='calculate_reserved_per', string='Reserved (%)')

 @api.depends('move_lines.product_uom_qty')
 def calculate_dmd_qty(self):
     for rs in self:
         dmdqty = 0
         for line in rs.move_ids_without_package:
             dmdqty += line.product_uom_qty
         rs.sum_dmd_qty = dmdqty

Comment: I used same xml like it's in the original post and removed all the other fields and left just "sum_reserved_qty"

Comment: In your original post it works, all you need is to revert the changes you made. You can make the field invisible.

Comment: really it's not working with me, could I ask you please to share with me the full code with XML code that is working with you

Comment: In python code, I changed the indentation of the two lines, restarted the server then I updated the module. I think that something is missing, you can't have that error from the code above.Check my edit.

Comment: really I copied your code but with no luck, can I ask for a favor sure if you accept, could you please send me the updated module so I can install directly, and if not sure I appreciate you all help, thanks

Comment: I created a [sample module](https://filebin.net/2q8ozrsunk3foces). The custom code can be found in `models.py` and `views.xml`

Comment: thank you very much for your kind help @Kenly, it's really helped